# Upgrade Magento 1.9 to latest version

Tags: magento-1.9, upgrade

I am planning to update Magento to latest version my current version is Magento ver. 1.9.0.1
I want to up upgrade it to ver. 1.9.1.0

What could be easiest and best way as I am not Magento expert?

What I though is Magento > admin > magento connect manager >

There I click check for updates to update it to latest one.

Is that only I have to do or what else steps needed.

Comment: just follow my answer at this link http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/21761/magento-upgrade-from-1-7-to-1-9/25156#25156

Comment: Nice, checkout this too https://magecomp.com/blog/how-to-upgrade-magento/

Answer (score 2):

For small incremental upgrades I would recommend the following process:

1. Make a complete development environment with the current backup of your site and database
2. Copy the new 1.9.1 files into your application. The easiest way to do this is using rsync. (`rsync -avz /from/path/ /to/path/live/`)
3. Visit your dev site (http://dev.mydomain.com) and run the upgrade
4. Test everything

Once you have done the above steps you can again make a complete backup of your site and database. You should add your ip to the Whitelist in your admin and set your maintenance.flag. This will ensure no one else visits your site.
The copy the new files into your application like you did in your dev environment.
Run you upgrade and you are set!

Comment: hi tried to update via magento connect after update i get blank page why so ??