# Error after upgrade, Failed opening 'Mage/Googlecheckout/Helper/Data.php' for inclusion

Tags: upgrade, log, error-log, varien-autoload

I upgraded Magento CE 1.7.0.2 to 1.9 and when I try to go to System > Configuration it just loads up blank.  I get the following errors in the system.log:

```
2015-03-13T19:27:52+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Mage/Googlecheckout/Helper/Data.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /chroot/home/path/to/html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2015-03-13T19:27:52+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Mage/Googlecheckout/Helper/Data.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /chroot/home/path/to/html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2015-03-13T19:27:52+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Mage/Googlecheckout/Helper/Data.php' for inclusion (include_path='/chroot/home/path/to/html/app/code/local:/chroot/home/path/to/html/app/code/community:/chroot/home/carbonfi/restore.carbonfibergear.com/html/app/code/core:/chroot/home/path/to/html/lib:.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php')  in /chroot/home/path/to/html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
```

Any ideas on what's causing the problem?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is a known Issue After Upgrading to CE 1.8.1 that affects you only if you do not follow the recommended procedure to upgrade to a new environment as discussed in Getting Ready For Your Upgrade.

Symptom: After completing the upgrade, when you log in to the Admin Panel and click System > Configuration, a fatal error similar to the following displays in your browser:

```
Class 'Mage_Googlecheckout_Helper_Data' not found in /var/www/html/magento/app/Mage.php on line 547
```

Solution:

Close the Admin Panel browser window.
As a user with root privileges, delete all files except config.xml from the following directory:

```
magento-install-dir/app/code/core/Mage/GoogleCheckout/etc
```

When you log back in to the Admin Panel, everything works as expected.

Comment: Thank you, worked perfect!  Are there any other known issues such as this I should be aware of?

Answer (score 2):

The problem isn't the upgrade procedure, if you skip some versions (i.e. from 1.7 to 1.9). The cause is, that in versions above 1.7 the path to GoogleCheckout is written with lower c,

```
ERR (3): Warning: include(Mage/Googlecheckout/Helper/Data.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /chroot/home/path/to/html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
                                    ^^^
```

but in the fileystem the path is named GoogleCheckout with upper C.

```
magento-install-dir/app/code/core/Mage/GoogleCheckout/etc
                                            ^^^
```

If you have the possibility, set a link with name Googlecheckout (lower c) to GoogleCheckout (upper C) and it will work. Otherwise rename magento-install-dir/app/code/core/Mage/GoogleCheckout to magento-install-dir/app/code/core/Mage/Googlecheckout.

Answer (score 0):

Not defined the Helper into the app/code/core/Mage/Googlecheckout/etc/config.xml file, so add this into it.

```
<global>
...
    <helpers>
        <googlecheckout>
            <class>Mage_GoogleCheckout_Helper</class>
        </googlecheckout>
    </helpers>
...
</global>
```