# Unable to upgrade to 1.9.2

Tags: magento-1.9, upgrade, magento-connect, ce-1.9.2.0, command-line

I am only able to install 1.9.1 with the following command:

```
./mage install http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community Mage_All_Latest --force
```

Comment: refer http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/21761/magento-upgrade-from-1-7-to-1-9/25156#25156 this for upgrade. always avoid upgrading through magento connect

Comment: I am looking for a simple straight forward method. Unzipping magento-1.9.2.0-2015-07-07-08-53-58.zip on my existing installation. Will this work?

Comment: No it won't because there could be files that were deleted in the newer version. Which would still be there if you would do it this way.

Comment: @7ochem Seriously? This is what the connect install does anyway (it's not that intelligent), and in discreet tar files that often fail to install properly. It doesn't delete anything, just overwrites. Otherwise people wouldn't have had to deal with the GoogleCheckout issue.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to ensure you system is fully upgraded is download the 1.9.2.0 update from here:

https://www.magentocommerce.com/download

Then extract all files and using FTP copy this to your Magento directory, overwriting all files. Then manually clear caches by deleting your var/cache folder.

Comment: Or if you have ssh access, upload it to your web server and run `tar -xzf magento-1.9.x.x.tar.gz` on it in the appropriate directory and save yourself all the headaches that ftp uploads entail such as halted uploads, partial uploads, etc. The initial tarfile upload goes massively faster and doesn't have the monumental directory recursion overhead of transferring all those small files that an FTP transfer has.