# Update magento from 1.9.1 to 1.9.2 gives blank screen

Tags: magento-1.9, ce-1.9.0.1, error, upgrade, ce-1.9.2.0

I just followed meticulously [this guide](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/21761/magento-upgrade-from-1-7-to-1-9) in order to upgrade from 1.9.1 to 1.9.2. I had no admin customizations so I did not do the last 3 points of the step number 4.

I did not had any local.xml file on my app/etc/ directory so I copied the old file to the new magento folder one and changed nothing on it. I uploaded then the shop to my server and the result is a blank page.

I can though see the admin page but I cannot login. What could be wrong? I would really fell appreciated for any ideas of what is wrong or how to search.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Around line #73 of index.php, there should be something like this:

```
#ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Uncomment that line (remove the "#"), reload your site in your browser, and it will likely generate an error. You can post that error here, or a quick Google search may also reveal the problem. I've encountered similar issues in the past, and it's usually permissions or db settings.

Comment: Thank you so very much! You actually gave me an answer that helps! While on other threads people have been voting down my question or even deleting it, you actually helped me out. I know know what the issue was. Unfortunately there is no fix (after googling the error I got) so I will just make a new Magento install and import all the products.

Very much appreciated, don't stop helping!