# The right way to upgrade Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, upgrade

I have a question regarding Magento upgrade.

I installed Magento 1.9.1.1 with n98-magerun and I have upgraded it to currently the latest version (1.9.2.1) via Downloader. Lets call this System A.

I also downloaded the latest version from Magento website. Lets call this System B.

When I compared the two Systems, I've noticed that the System B has a folder 'dev' with tests that is absent in System A.

What is the correct way to upgrade the System A, that I get the System B as a result?

Why does this inequality occur?

Comment: avoid upgrading of magento thru downloader. and use this link for the upgrade http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/21761/magento-upgrade-from-1-7-to-1-9/25156#25156

Answer (score 2):

I would strongly advise against using Magento connect or downloader to upgrade Magento.

In your example you have downloaded a fresh copy of Magento (system B) I would unzip this into a temp folder and the use rsync to replace all files in system A with those from system B (the upgrade).

I like to use rsync to do this :

```
rsync -avI –exclude=app/etc/local.xml –exclude=app/etc/config.xml –exclude=index.php –exclude=.htaccess ./magento/ /home/www/magento/
```

Where /home/www/magento is the path to the 1.9.1.x installation. After copying reset your file permissions

You muse be certain that you have not modified any core magento code, locale or template files as they will be overwritten. I would test the upgrade first on your development system.

When you do this in your live store the process would be

1. backup magento db and files
2. take store offline i.e. n98-magerun.phar sys:maintenance
3. disable cache : n98-magerun.phar cache:disable
4. rsync files
5. update modman modules (if you use modman) modman update-all --force
6. reset permissions
7. login to magento
8. enable cache
9. **TEST**

More info here http://blog.gaiterjones.com/upgrade-magento-ce-1-9-1-x-to-1-9-2-0/