# Keeping Magento Database, Using Fresh Files

Tags: magento-1.9, database, magento-community, installation

I have Magento CE 1.9.2.1. The database is just fine, but the files are messed up. I'd like to keep the database and just replace the files and start designing from scratch. Is this possible? If so, how could I go about doing this?

I know I'd have to keep the 'media' folder to keep my product images. Anything else I would need to worry about?

Comment: `app/etc/local.xml` if you don't want to add this again for DB/session/cache config. and also any community extension or customizations that you added

Comment: Which "files are messed up"?

Comment: Mainly theme related files and whatnot. I just want to start fresh, but don't want to lose any products, pictures, and customer info.

Comment: Basically, I plan on wiping the files and copying new fresh files to my root directory. As long as I keep the 'media' folder and 'app/etc/local.xml' I should be good? The only customizations were to theme files and I won't be keeping any extensions. I'll be installing a whole new theme designed for version 1.9.

Answer (score 0):

If you have extensions installed and there's an entry in the database, using the database without the previously installed extensions will cause errors. So you can try uninstalling the extensions via Connect or manually comb through the database for mentions of the extensions.

You can follow the same steps outlined here and omit if not required:
[Magento upgrade from 1.7 to 1.9](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/21761/magento-upgrade-from-1-7-to-1-9)

Any custom files and xml in `app/code/local`, `app/etc/local.xml`,  `app/etc/modules/`, `app/js/` and `/media` will do if you're using a new theme.