# Magento 1.7.0.2 patch SUPEE-6788 fails

Tags: magento-1.7, patches, supee-6788

I am trying to patch a Magento 1.7.0.2 with the

PATCH_SUPEE-6788_CE_1.7.0.2_v1-2015-10-27-12-00-16.sh

I have solved several line ending problems and missing .htaccess.sample ...

But these file cannot be patched:

```
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Admin.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 131.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file     
app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Admin.php.rej

patching file lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 410.
Hunk #2 FAILED at 474.
2 out of 2 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file     
lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php.rej
```

I downloaded a fresh Magento 1.7.0.2 copy (from
https://www.magentocommerce.com/download) and tried to apply the patch on it but also failed.

Checked the lines mentioned on CLI (like FAILED at 131) but I did not found anything suspicious.

Also it did not write any .rej files

Any advise ?

Comment: Read this artikel

http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/21761/magento-upgrade-from-1-7-to-1-9

Answer (score 3):

You must apply the previous patches first.

`lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php` has been modified by patch **SUPEE-5344** already, and `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Admin.php` by **SUPEE-5994**.

A fresh 1.7.0.2 copy does not contain any of the patches, so you need to apply all that have been released afterwards *in order*

You can look up the necessary patches for each version in [this matrix](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MTbU9Bq130zrrsJwLIB9d8qnGfYZnkm4jBlfNaBF19M/edit#gid=0) (select the Magento CE sheet!).

#### Patches for Magento CE 1.7.0.2:

1. APPSEC-212
2. SUPEE-1533
3. SUPEE-5344
4. SUPEE-5994
5. SUPEE-6285
6. SUPEE-6482
7. SUPEE-6788