# Magento 1.9 How to use old database while installing fresh magento

Tags: magento-1.9, database

I wish to install fresh magento 1.9.2.3 using the same database of magento 1.9.2.2
During installation process when I give the same database name as of magento 1.9.2.2 It shows error as"Database connection error". Is it possible to use the same old database or should I create a new one?

Comment: upgrade your magento 1.9.2.2 to 1.9.2.3

Comment: follow this link http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/21761/magento-upgrade-from-1-7-to-1-9/25156#25156

Comment: was the method I followed wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Answer Found. The method which I followed was correct.We can give the old database name & its details (username and password) during fresh installation to use the old database in new magento.Database error occured. But once I restarted the xampp server the error disappeared.It was that simple and that easy.

Answer (score 0):

no you are wrong, you **must never** install new magento on top of your old database, in fact you wont be able to install it, or you will break it.

but instead you have to in magento 1.9.2.3 change details in local.xml to connect to your old database and open your index page to trigger the updates...

Comment: How to do that?

Comment: I didnt break my site. the new one is working perfectly fine. The result of my mistake is that my old store is redirecting to the new one. Can I not retrieve my old site?