# upgrading from 1.9.0.1 to 1.9.2.4

Tags: magento-1.9, ce-1.9.0.1, upgrade, ce-1.9.2.4

I am new in magento, i need to know how to upgrade magento 1.9.0.1 to 1.9.2.4

(I use ubuntu 15.04, what are the necessary commands ? )

Thanks for help :)

Comment: Have you tried anything yet ??

Comment: Easiest way with possible issue fixes https://magecomp.com/blog/how-to-upgrade-magento/

Answer (score 5):

### Upgrade Roadmap for CE 1.9.2.4 from 1.9.0.1

1. Take a backup of current database and current 1.9.0.1 code. place `maintenance.flag` file inside 1.9.0.1 code folder to put website offline.
2. Download latest magento from the http://www.magentocommerce.com/download
3. Remove all folders and files from your 1.9.0.1 code except `maintenance.flag` (but you should have backup somewhere) and place all folders and files from the 1.9.2.4.
4. Now from your 1.9.0.1 merge your following custom folders into the 1.9.2.4

   - Community `app/code/community`
   - Local `app/code/local`
   - Media
   - your theme or package (`app/design/frontend/default/<your theme>` or `app/design/frontend/<your package>`)
   - custom folders from Skin (both for adminhtml and frontend).
   - copy your custom xml files from `app/etc/modules/` to current `app/etc/modules/`
   - any custom admin theme folder from `adminhtml/default/yourtheme`.
   - copy your custom folders from `adminhtml/default/default/` (1.9.0.1) to adminhtml/default/default/ (1.9.2.4).
   - custom js files if any from `app/js/`.
5. Now go to `app/etc/local.xml`.Edit database details their.put your database username and password and database name.
6. Remove `maintenance.flag` file and check the site in the browser. it is done.

P.S. For more inforrmation on magento upgrade you can refer [THIS](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/21761/magento-upgrade-from-1-7-to-1-9/25156#25156)

Comment: Great help from these steps. Thanks Man.