# How to safly upgrade Magento version 1.7 to Magento 2.0

Tags: magento-1.7, magento2, upgrade

We are planning to upgrade Magento version 1.7 to 2.0,

As we have a very custom build Magento 1.7 version.

We have developed many custom scripts and many plugins for our store.

We have a large amount of data on 9+ Million parts.

So now we want to upgrade it to version 2.0.

We want to know what are the safety steps/tips we should follow during this phase.

Also what is the differences while upgrading.

How we should start this upgrading process.

Looking for this kind of [answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/21761/magento-upgrade-from-1-7-to-1-9) but in more detail if possible

Any guidance/thoughts are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For migration from magento 1 to magento 2 you have to migrate or convert following details
   a) Data
   b) Theme
   c) Customization you did 
   d) Extension

For more information on this please follow.
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/howdoi/migrate/migrate.html

1) Export and Import your Customers, Orders and Product Details.

2) Use any comparison tools like Beyond Compare to check if is there any core files modification exist. if exist make a note of it.

3) Compare the third party extension if you have modified it or not and make a list of it.

4) Check whether you have directly created database tables (Without using Extension script). if exist make a note of it.

5) Check Availability of Third party extension available for magento 2. if you not exist you have to convert it yourself.

6) Install Magento 2 Latest version and Import the data

7) Install third party extension available for magento 2, which you have already installed in magento 1. Modify it according to the result of Step 3.

8) Build Extension by yourself which are not available or you have build for your own purpose.

9) Write Custom Plugin for the report you get from step 2 and a plugin for orphan database tables.

Hope you understand the concern.

Thanks

Comment: How can I make changes in my custom scripts like generating reports or uploading products using csv/xls file. As in Magento 2 Mage() is not available. so is there any solutions to connect with magneto code via external scripts.

Comment: As i have mentioned earlier in steps 2,  Report will give you list of files modified and the code snippet which is added or removed from the core files. You have to write those equivalent changes manually in magento 2.

Comment: I think it also help to write external code in magneto root http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/39981/how-can-i-create-my-dirty-playground-file-in-magento-2

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, as I know, you can not upgrade an extension from Magento 1.7 to 2.0. So you should be sure to decide to upgrade Magento 2 now when the number of Magento 2 is limited compared Magento 1.x.
Secondly, in my opinion, you can upgrade Magento 2 using Composer that change in `composer.json`. It is safer for your database. The statistic of errors of data loss, unsuccessful updates or site breakdown is lower than upgrade via admin. However, it require experience about using command line that has steep learning curve.