# Ways of upgrading magento1.8.1.0 to magento1.9.2

Tags: magento-1.9

Hi Guys i have already running with magento1.8.1.0 need to upgrade magento 1.9.2 kindly let me know all the way that i can perform this task

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/21761/magento-upgrade-from-1-7-to-1-9/25156#25156

Answer (score 0):

**Via FTP**

1. Download Magento 1.9.2 to your local
2. Take Backup of your live site
3. Disable cache and compiler
4. Upload the new Magento into your live
5. site Visit your site
6. refresh your cache and reindex

**Via Magento Downloader**

1- Login to Magento Downloaded

2- Click Check for upgrade

3- Select new version for each module

4- Upgrade

5- refresh your cache and reindex

**Via Command Line**

1- chmod 700 mage

2- ./mage install http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community Mage_All_Latest --force

3- ./mage list-upgrades

4- ./mage upgrade-all

5- refresh your cache and reindex