# Migrate to magento 1.7.0.2 to 1.9.2.4 ( last version )

Tags: upgrade

I want to upgrade my store ( orders, products, categories ) from magento v.1.7 to v. 1.9 ( last ). How i can proceed without lost or broken a webiste/DB ?

Answer (score 2):

It depends a lot on your specific project that we know nothing about. I usually would mark this question as duplicate of [Magento upgrade from 1.7 to 1.9](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/21761/magento-upgrade-from-1-7-to-1-9?rq=1) but IMHO it is not answered adequately there either and it looks like you would be satisfied with a **data migration without extensions, themes and custom code**, which makes the question a bit different.

In that case you can try to point a fresh 1.9 installation to a copy of your current database and Magentos upgrade scripts will run to add/modify tables.

**But** if any extensions added EAV attributes with custom source/frontend/backend models, you will get fatal errors until you removed those attributes. Check the `eav_attribute` table to see if that's the case for you.

Of course you can also add those extensions back. If possible in a recent version that's compatible with 1.9.

The most critical parts in upgrades are themes and project specific customizations. If those are not an issue for you, the upgrade is a lot less painful.

**And in case it was not obvious: Don't do upgrades directly on the production server!**

Comment: Thanks for answer, i want only to transfer order, user and categories. I don't need to move extensions and theme.

Answer (score 1):

I have recently done this to a store I work on. There are very few/no big database changes, so if you have un-modified core files it should be quite painless.  There are some examples here;

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23932371/upgrading-from-1-7-to-1-9-magento

Be sure to take backups before you do and I would recommend testing the upgrade on a dev site before making any live changes.

Answer (score 1):

You can update your Magento 1.x version by following these steps:

1. Magento Compilation from System > Tools > Compilation > Disable
2. Magento Cache from System > Cache Management > Select All > Action: Disable > Submit
3. Remove all files and folders from your Magento v1.7 directory (make sure to keep your backup in a safe place) and place all files and folders from Magento v1.9.x package.
4. Open your favorite web browser, go to your link. You will be asked to install fresh Magento v1.9.x store but don’t worry, keep going and when you will reach to the Configuration page. Fill it up with the same information you used for your previous Magento v1.7 store which includes SQL DB Server Hostname, SQL DB Name, SQL Server Username, SQL Server Password, Base URL and Admin Path.
5. Once you finish the installation, do not visit frontend or backend page. From your Magento v1.7 files and folders backup, copy and merge following files and folders into your new Magento v1.9.x store directory:

   - Community Folder: ROOT > app > code > community
   - Local Folder: ROOT > app > code > local
   - Media Folder in Root Directory: ROOT > media
   - Your Theme Folder: ROOT > app > design > frontend > default (package name) > “your_theme” (If you are using “default” package for your theme then just copy theme folder otherwise you need to copy the whole package which includes your theme folder)
   - Skin Folder in Root Directory: ROOT > skin
   - Module’s Custom XML Files: ROOT > app > etc > modules > “your_custom_XML_files”
   - Admin Theme Folder: ROOT > app > design > adminhtml > default
   - Custom JS Folder: ROOT > app > js
   - Now finally delete everything from ROOT > var > cache and from ROOT >
     var > sessions to clear all sessions and cache.