# Import existing Magento1.9.0.1 DB to the new Magento 1.9.2.4

Tags: magento-1.9, database, upgrade, migration, ce-1.9.2.4

we have a Magento 1.9.0.1 single store application,also we have customer, category and product in this version, my client like to develop the with Magento 1.9.2.4 with new theme,also he wants to use the same Database to this new version, so I export the existing magento1.9.0.1 DB, and used that DB for my new version of Magento 1.9.2.4

but unfortunately, the product count is a mismatch, as well as the product details also not same.

I manually compare the product related information to the both version its mismatching.

I don't know where is the problem occurs, do you have any idea regarding this kindly let me know

Comment: just upgrade your magento version

Comment: refer this link for upgrade magento version http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/21761/magento-upgrade-from-1-7-to-1-9/25156#25156

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you not to work with Magento database. Just upgrade your Magento site from admin, so you don't need to work manually and database will be moved to the new version automatically.