# Magento 1.9.3.0 always redirects to home after update from 1.7.0.2

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7

I updated a Magento 1.7.0.2 to 1.9.3.0 and at first glance everything looks fine, no errors thrown so far.

I followed the instructions described here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/25156

But now every page is being redirected to the homepage. Even if I delete the .htaccess file and prefix the url path after the tld with an index.php.

The database is still in the same state as before the update.
I changed the base URLs to `http://localhost/` in the db and deleted the whole var/cache directory.

Needless to say, I'm doing the update locally first.
What could cause this behaviour? Thanks for your help!

Comment: system->configuration->Web->Url Options->Auto-redirect to Base URL set that to No

Comment: The problem is that I  can reach the admin login page but after logging in I get redirected to the homepage. So I can't edit the backend. I think I have to make the changes to the db directly. But I don't know where.

Comment: core_config_data table, what do you have as your base url?

Comment: also truncate your core_url_rewrite and do a --reindexall , flush the cache and see if that helps

Comment: base url is http://localhost. How can I do a reindexall when I'm not able to reach the admin panel?

Comment: by commandline, cd to shell folder and then do php indexer.php --reindexall

Comment: but first truncate your core__url_rewrite

Comment: core_url_rewrite was already empty. The php indexer.php --reindexall doesn't work. Do you mean php index.php --reindexall? But that only outputs the content of index.php. Probably I'm getting your advice wrong ...

Comment: https://www.branded3.com/blog/re-indexing-magento-command-line/

Comment: OK, I understand. But now I'm getting into trouble: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: PDO::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in path/to/project/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php:128


Stack trace:

#0 path/to/project/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(128): PDO->__construct('mysql:model=mys...', 'magento', 'magento', Array)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46831/discussion-between-nickool-and-citizen404).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some debugging and recognized that there was some strange behaviour regarding the sessions. They were already expired just when they were created.

And then I recieved an email from the Magento team which states that there are several issues with the latest release of Magento 1.9.3.0 CE.
Looking at the last point in the list, I noticed that it is a bug in the core of the 1.9.3.0 update. So I followed the advice of the Magento team and refused the 1.9.3.0 update and installed 1.9.2.4 combined with the latest security patch SUPEE-8788 instead.

Now everything works as expected.

> Several issues with our most recent Community Edition 1.9.3 release
>   have been reported. Some affect functionality critical to store
>   operations and we are working on a new release (Community Edition
>   1.9.3.1) that is tentatively scheduled for the end of next week. Magento is aware of the following issues:
>
> - Search results return all store product
> - Some integrations using Magento APIs no longer work
> - Bundled product prices do not update
> - Store-specific attribute labels disappear
> - Auto generated passwords do not work for some customers
> - Exceptions appear for stores with disabled breadcrumbs
> - Free shipping sales rules are not calculated correctly
> - **PHP warnings occur with the session timestamp variable**
>
> We recommend that you wait to upgrade to Community Edition 1.9.3 and
>   instead apply the latest security patch, SUPEE-8788, which does not
>   have these issues.
>
> If you have already upgraded, are experiencing issues, and cannot wait
>   for the new release, the Magento community has created a module that
>   resolves the issues outlined above. It can be found at
>   https://github.com/digitalpianism/bugfixes. Magento has not tested
>   this module. If you decide to use it, we recommend you remove the
>   community module and upgrade to Enterprise Edition 1.14.3.1 as soon as
>   it is available.