# Magento 1.9.3 Upgrade Missing core_email_queue_recipients table

Tags: magento-1.9, database

After upgrading Magento 1.9.1 to 1.9.3.1 manually via FTP, the site works fine except when you get to the checkout success page. It is blank.

The exception log shows that the core_email_queue_recipients table is missing.

Checking the database with MySQL Workbench shows that it is indeed missing. I am assuming that the SQL upgrade script did not fire, but I have no idea how to fire this.

Some sources say to go to the core_resources table and modify the database version value there to make it fire, but they don't mention which 'code' field value is the database version. See https://community.magento.com/t5/Version-Upgrades/1-9-0-1-to-1-9-2-2-missing-core-email-queue-table/td-p/22350

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's little tricky and requires some research.

You can go to `core_resources` table and find the `core_setup`.

Now, check the `version and data_version`.

Then, go to `Mage/Core/sql/core_setup/upgrade-1.6.0.5-1.6.0.6.php`

If you don't find this file, then you might not have copied all files properly.

If you can confirm you have missed that file then simply see what is your last file in `Mage/Core/sql/core_setup` folder and get the version number from there.

For example if you find the file name as: `mysql4-upgrade-0.8.5-0.8.6.php` then I will **copy `0.8.6`** as my version.

Now, copy all missing files in that [folder](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/tree/d48bebc211cc216aaf78bdf25d7f0b0143d6333b/app/code/core/Mage/Core/sql/core_setup) and change `core_setup`'s `version and data_version` as `0.8.6` in database. Then, go to `Mage/etc/config.xml` and change the version name here too.

And clear the cache.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I don't see this path on the server or in the Magento download for 1.9.3.1 CE at https://magento.com/tech-resources/download under the 8th section labeled ver 1.9.3.1 - Added Nov 14, 2016. The closest thing to it is app/code/core/Mage but there isn't a sql folder there.

Comment: It's `app/code/core/` then the `Mage/Core/sql/core_setup`

Comment: Thanks - found it. In that folder there are the following files 
install-1.6.0.0.php
mysql4-data-upgrade-1.6.0.2-1.6.0.3.php
mysql4-install-0.7.0.php
mysql4-install-0.8.0.php
mysql4-upgrade-0.6.26-0.7.0.php
mysql4-upgrade-0.7.1-0.7.2.php
mysql4-upgrade-0.7.2-0.7.3.php
mysql4-upgrade-0.7.3-0.7.4.php
mysql4-upgrade-0.7.4-0.7.5.php
mysql4-upgrade-0.7.5-0.7.6.php
mysql4-upgrade-0.7.6-0.7.7.php
mysql4-upgrade-0.7.7-0.7.8.php
mysql4-upgrade-0.7.8-0.7.9.php
mysql4-upgrade-0.8.0-0.8.1.php
mysql4-upgrade-0.8.1-0.8.2.php
mysql4-upgrade-0.8.2-0.8.3.php
mysql4-upgrade-0.8.3-0.8.4.php

Comment: mysql4-upgrade-0.8.4-0.8.5.php
mysql4-upgrade-0.8.5-0.8.6.php
mysql4-upgrade-0.8.6-0.8.7.php
mysql4-upgrade-0.8.7-0.8.8.php
mysql4-upgrade-0.8.8-0.8.9.php
mysql4-upgrade-0.8.9-0.8.10.php
mysql4-upgrade-0.8.10-0.8.11.php
mysql4-upgrade-0.8.11-0.8.12.php
mysql4-upgrade-0.8.12-0.8.13.php
mysql4-upgrade-0.8.13-0.8.14.php
mysql4-upgrade-0.8.14-0.8.15.php
mysql4-upgrade-0.8.15-0.8.16.php
mysql4-upgrade-0.8.16-0.8.17.php
mysql4-upgrade-0.8.17-0.8.18.php
mysql4-upgrade-0.8.18-0.8.19.php
mysql4-upgrade-0.8.19-0.8.20.php
mysql4-upgrade-0.8.20-0.8.21.php

Comment: mysql4-upgrade-0.8.21-0.8.22.php
mysql4-upgrade-0.8.22-0.8.23.php
mysql4-upgrade-0.8.23-0.8.24.php
mysql4-upgrade-0.8.24-0.8.25.php
mysql4-upgrade-0.8.25-0.8.26.php
mysql4-upgrade-0.8.26-0.8.27.php
mysql4-upgrade-0.8.27-0.8.28.php
mysql4-upgrade-1.5.9.9-1.6.0.0.php
upgrade-1.6.0.1-1.6.0.2.php
upgrade-1.6.0.2-1.6.0.3.php
upgrade-1.6.0.3-1.6.0.4.php
upgrade-1.6.0.5-1.6.0.6.php

Comment: So my question is: do I use the mysql4-upgrade-0.8.27-0.8.28.php file as the guide or the mysql4-upgrade-1.5.9.9-1.6.0.0.php file as my guide?

Comment: What about version in database? Can you check?

Comment: I am having some issues with MySQL Workbench right now and am unable to run queries. I'll fix it but when I looked earlier I saw more 1.6.0.0's than I did 0.8.28's (dont' recall seeing them).

Comment: core_setup in the core_resource table has 1.6.0.6 as both the version and data_version values. The Mage/Core/etc/config.xml file is also set to 1.6.0.6. Should I change all these values to 1.6.0.5 to get it to fire? Or 1.6.0.0?

Comment: Now, it's going to be very tricky. You will need to find how many files are not executed. And change the version accordingly. You should check each files starting from last and see if that code has executed. And determine till which file it has executed. Also, it is very strange that how come this file didn't execute `upgrade-1.6.0.5-1.6.0.6.php` .

Comment: Would modifying this value to 1.6.0.0 in both the database and config.xml file, then clearing the cache, then modifying it to 1.6.0.1 in both the database and config.xml file, then clearing the cache, RINSE/REPEAT until I reach 1.6.0.6 get me to the same place? Or should I examine each of these files starting from 1.6.0.0 to 1.6.0.6 like you suggested earlier to see what was modified/what wasn't?

Comment: It's very important all those files get called, otherwise you may miss other features which you don't know yet. So, it's very important to know which files are missed from executing. Once you know which files are not executed then you change the db and in config.xml accordingly.

Comment: Well a quick search of all these files includes no mention of core_email_queue_recipients so no matter what it looks like I'm missing this table. 

I'm going to roll back this update to an earlier server snapshot. How would you suggest upgrading from my 1.9.1 to 1.9.3.1?

Comment: You can check this: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/21761/magento-upgrade-from-1-7-to-1-9/25156#25156

Comment: I rolled the server back due to uneasiness about these tables missing. The database version in core_resource was likely set to 1.6.0.6 before I updated from 1.9.0.1 to 1.9.1 due to a security patch error.
 
When the website completed its update it did not execute the .SQL update file. Changing core_setup in core_resource table from 1.6.0.6 to 1.6.0.5 caused the SQL file to run and properly update the database. So your solution was correct and I confirmed at https://community.magento.com/t5/Version-Upgrades/1-9-0-1-to-1-9-2-2-missing-core-email-queue-table/td-p/22350