# Getting all customer information

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, customer

Heloo,

I want to get my all customer information i want to just export all table my table and install in other site but both version are not same new site is in 1.8.0.2 it can may be problematic ?and which table are related to customer information so i can be do my stuff

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/10651/magento-upgrade-from-1-7-to-1-8

Comment: @julien i dont want to upgrade but i start new site and getting all customer from existing once.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/272452/magento2-how-can-i-get-all-customers-from-database-tables

Answer (score 2):

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection')
               ->addNameToSelect()
               ->addAttributeToSelect('email')
               ->addAttributeToSelect('created_at')
               ->addAttributeToSelect('group_id')
               ->joinAttribute('billing_street', 'customer_address/street', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
               ->joinAttribute('billing_postcode', 'customer_address/postcode', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
               ->joinAttribute('billing_city', 'customer_address/city', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
               ->joinAttribute('billing_telephone', 'customer_address/telephone', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
               ->joinAttribute('billing_fax', 'customer_address/fax', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
               ->joinAttribute('billing_region', 'customer_address/region', 'default_billing', null, 'left')
               ->joinAttribute('billing_country_code', 'customer_address/country_id', 'default_billing', null, 'left')

               ->joinAttribute('shipping_street', 'customer_address/street', 'default_shipping', null, 'left')
               ->joinAttribute('shipping_postcode', 'customer_address/postcode', 'default_shipping', null, 'left')
               ->joinAttribute('shipping_city', 'customer_address/city', 'default_shipping', null, 'left')
               ->joinAttribute('shipping_telephone', 'customer_address/telephone', 'default_shipping', null, 'left')
               ->joinAttribute('shipping_fax', 'customer_address/fax', 'default_shipping', null, 'left')
               ->joinAttribute('shipping_region', 'customer_address/region', 'default_shipping', null, 'left')
               ->joinAttribute('shipping_country_code', 'customer_address/country_id', 'default_shipping', null, 'left')
               ->joinAttribute('taxvat', 'customer/taxvat', 'entity_id', null, 'left');
```

Or if you want via mysql query:

```
SELECT ce.*, ea.attribute_code, 
    CASE ea.backend_type 
       WHEN 'varchar' THEN ce_varchar.value
       WHEN 'int' THEN ce_int.value
       WHEN 'text' THEN ce_text.value
       WHEN 'decimal' THEN ce_decimal.value
       WHEN 'datetime' THEN ce_datetime.value
       ELSE NULL
    END AS value
  FROM customer_entity AS ce 
  LEFT JOIN eav_attribute AS ea ON ce.entity_type_id = ea.entity_type_id
  LEFT JOIN customer_entity_varchar AS ce_varchar ON ce.entity_id = ce_varchar.entity_id AND ea.attribute_id = ce_varchar.attribute_id AND ea.backend_type = 'varchar'
  LEFT JOIN customer_entity_int AS ce_int ON ce.entity_id = ce_int.entity_id AND ea.attribute_id = ce_int.attribute_id AND ea.backend_type = 'int'
  LEFT JOIN customer_entity_text AS ce_text ON ce.entity_id = ce_text.entity_id AND ea.attribute_id = ce_text.attribute_id AND ea.backend_type = 'text'
  LEFT JOIN customer_entity_decimal AS ce_decimal ON ce.entity_id = ce_decimal.entity_id AND ea.attribute_id = ce_decimal.attribute_id AND ea.backend_type = 'decimal'
  LEFT JOIN customer_entity_datetime AS ce_datetime ON ce.entity_id = ce_datetime.entity_id AND ea.attribute_id = ce_datetime.attribute_id AND ea.backend_type = 'datetime'
```

Comment: i just want table name ...

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: Can it be right approach to direct import in new one and it can be create problem ? because older version is 1.7.0.2 and new one is 1.8.0.1

Comment: You mean upgrade magento, if yes you should probably go with magento standards

Comment: not for upgrade i create another website and i want to get all customer list from another site.

Comment: I guess use this link, may be this is what you need:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20225176/how-to-move-customer-from-one-website-to-another-in-magento

Comment: Why all people talking on update instead of giving answer of my question.; :(