# Magento2: How can i get all Customers from database tables

Tags: magento2, customer

I want to get all Customers record (including their address) from database.How many tables i have to dump for.Kindly enlist the tables names here.
How many tables which i have to dump and import another database and getting the all customers and customers will be able to login the site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**All Customer Data Including Logs In This Table :-**

```
customer_address_entity;
customer_address_entity_datetime;
customer_address_entity_decimal;
customer_address_entity_int;
customer_address_entity_text;
customer_address_entity_varchar;
customer_entity;
customer_entity_datetime;
customer_entity_decimal;
customer_entity_int;
customer_entity_text;
customer_entity_varchar;
```