# Upgrade options via Magento Connect is not available on Magento version 1.7.0.2

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-community, upgrade, magento-connect

I'm working on upgrading one of Magento site version 1.7.0.2 to 1.9.1.1 via Magento Connect. For some reason after I click on "check for upgrade" button, the page does not show any drop options except "reinstall" and "uninstall" on the available column, all fields are empty where they were supposed to version 1.9.1.1 or the latest version of modules.

This issue doesn't occur on another Magento site that I upgrade from 1.9.0.1 to 1.9.1.1.

Could this be permission issue or glitch on Magento connect? or does upgrading from 1.7.0.2 to 1.9.1.1 has be done manually outside Magento Connect at this point?

Thank you,

Comment: Hello, I recommended manual for safe upgrade. Follow [link](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/10651/magento-upgrade-from-1-7-to-1-8) to upgrade

Comment: Hi there. Thank you for the link. Does this also apply to version 1.9.1.1 or is it specific to 1.8?

Comment: Hi, this will upgrade latest stable version of magento. Please look point No 8 ./pear upgrade -f magento-core/Mage_All_Latest-stable.  Hope this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Me too stuck with this once.

The only solution i found is to open curl.php in /downloader/lib/Mage/HTTP/Client and go to makeRequest function.

there inside that function just put $https = false in the beginning and save and upload it.

See this for more: http://www.shyamkrishna.co.in/2016/09/upgrade-options-via-magento-connect-is.html

Comment: Thanks for sharing the knowledge. I actually ended up giving up on using Magento Connect and just upgrade the store via command line instead.

Comment: i think even if you tried using cmd, you might get an error like this "ssl error", i think.